# Slow down android accelerometer updated

Tags: android, accelerometer, power-management

Is there a way to make the sampling frequency of the accelerometer in Android lower than the frequency set with the `SENSOR_DELAY_UI` constant?

I want to make my app eat less battery, and this looks like a good way to achieve that. (I've already slowed things down from `SENSOR_DELAY_GAME` to `SENSOR_DELAY_UI`, and the result was quite good -- the battery lasted much longer.)

Would the sensor event listener even have an impact on battery life?

Or would filtering them and avoiding further CPU heavy computations only be sufficient in this case?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can input a value in microseconds as well as the preset rates.  Call the method like this: `registerListener(SensorEventListener listener, Sensor sensor, int rate)`, where `rate` is either a integer value specified in microseconds or one of the following constants:

- SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL
- SENSOR_DELAY_UI
- SENSOR_DELAY_GAME
- SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST

Example:

```
sensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
```

[Source document on the Android development site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#registerListener%28android.hardware.SensorEventListener,%20android.hardware.Sensor,%20int%29).